# 100w USB-C to DC power adapter charging issues

Tags: usb, laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I've been encountering some issues with a custom charging setup for my Razer Blade 15 laptop. My blade is a 2020 model that does not support USB-C charging. I wanted a more compact solution than the stock charger, so I opted for a USB-C to DC cable paired with a DC to Razer Blade charging port adapter. I'm using a 100w wall adapter, and both cables support 100w power delivery (links provided below).

The laptop will charge but, I encounter an odd issue where the laptop charges for a brief 3-10 seconds, then stops, and then resumes charging again in that same short interval. This "start-stop-start" cycle keeps repeating.

I'm aware that Razer doesn’t recommend using third-party chargers. Additionally, I understand that to harness the laptop's full potential, especially for high-performance tasks, the 230w power supply that comes with it is necessary. But as a student, I primarily use my laptop for lighter tasks like browsing on Chrome, streaming on Spotify, etc., in class. Hence, I assumed this 100w setup would suffice for those quick charges in between lessons.

I am wondering if there is an issue with the amount of power the laptop is getting. I do not know how electricity works but the cable is rated for 5 amps which I wonder if that is enough.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09KT1QH84/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KT1QH84)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0C1FZWT8M/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C1FZWT8M)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09HXDTFBG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HXDTFBG)

Comment: Sounds like the charger tries to perform a smart charge calibration and the laptop fails to understand this and the charger aborts, then the cycle repeats. You should definitely not do this or you will brick the charger